# libvlc media player in C#

Tags: c#, .net, media-player, libvlc

Hey guys and girls :) ok so i ran this project -> 
http://www.helyar.net/2009/libvlc-media-player-in-c-part-2/ and it worked perfectly (he was using .net 2.0) however when i try anything above 3.5 it gives -> 
Unable to load DLL ‘libvlc’: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

is there any workaround someone has done that sorts this out? MANY thanks ppl :D:D:D:D

Comment: it says clrealy "The specified module could not be found." so whats your problem? add dll's to program dir.

Answer (score 6):

There are two things that must be done when using that example with the new 2.0.x VLC releases.  First, you have to somehow add the libvlc DLL to the search path.  I used a call to SetDllDirectory to do the trick.  You declare it as:

```
static class LibVlc
{
    . . .
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);
    . . .
}
```

Then you can call this method with the root folder of the VLC installation.  On my PC, I called it as follows:

```
LibVlc.SetDllDirectory(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC");
```

Obviously, for a program being distributed this parameter should be configurable.

Next, the VLC API's have apparently changed because none of the methods require an exception object to be passed in anymore.  It looks like return values from the methods should be checked (for example, libvlc_new() returns NULL if there was an error).  I haven't tried passing in the exception object by reference like he does but the calls all work fine without it (and my interfaces now match the VLC API exactly).  I also specify the calling convention to use when doing interop, just to be clear to the runtime what I expect for parameter passing order and such.  For example, here are my defines for libvlc_new and libvlc_release:

```
[DllImport("libvlc", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr libvlc_new(int argc,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,
     ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string[] argv);

[DllImport("libvlc", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void libvlc_release(IntPtr instance);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You must copy `libvlc.dll` to your `bin/debug` folder. It must be the one from your VLC installation folder (`C:\program files\videolan\vlc`)

Comment: I get this after doing that : A call to PInvoke function 'MyLibVLC!MyLibVLC.LibVlc::libvlc_new' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: the API has been updated since that article has been written and the calls defined in it is out of date. Solutions: a) Fix the p/invoke definitions b) Download the same VLC version as the article author used.